# SUM IF condition true echo description

Tags: php, mysql

Detail:

```
lo means layout
lo_act_id ( activity id ), lo_time ( time spent ) , up_time and down_time , lo_description , lo_client_id
```

if activity id < to 99 means up-time

if activity id > to 99 means downtime but I've downtime, I would like to see the note/cause of it.

This is the query I use its works great but I dont know how to take and show the `lo_description`

```
SELECT * , 
  SUM( IF( `lo_act_id` > 99 , lo_time , 0 )) AS down_time,
  SUM( IF( `lo_act_id` < 99 , lo_time , 0 ,lo_desc )) AS up_time
FROM tbl_Layout
LEFT  JOIN tbl_Client ON lo_client_id=client_code
GROUP BY lo_client_id
```

This is what I got

```
Client   Spent Time  Downtime
1        216           3 
20       250           0 
16       10           16 
35       60            0
60       30            0
```

**This is what I'd like to get:**

```
Client    Spend Time    Downtime    Note
1         216           3           Replace Network Card
20        250           0     
16        10            16          Replace Main Board
                                    Monthly Maintenance
                                    Hurricane affect facilities
35        60            0
60        30            0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`CAST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html) to get rid of the "Min" and "minutes" (assuming that this field always holds minutes, not seconds or hours).

Use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to stick together the descriptions.

```
SELECT
  tbl_Client.*,
  SUM(IF(`lo_act_id` > 99, CAST(lo_time AS UNSIGNED), 0)) AS down_time,
  SUM(IF(`lo_act_id` < 99, CAST(lo_time AS UNSIGNED), 0)) AS up_time,
  GROUP_CONCAT(IF(`lo_act_id` > 99, lo_description, NULL) SEPARATOR "\n") AS note
FROM tbl_Layout
LEFT JOIN tbl_Client ON lo_client_id=client_code
GROUP BY lo_client_id
```